# the email address are not returned from stored procedure in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

The values are not passed to `EmailTO` and `EmailFrom` from stored procedure, its showing NULL. So I am not able to send Email. If I enter the email address manually in the place of `To` and `From` then the email is sent in smtp form but its not reading from stored procedure.

Please help me in retrieving the values:

This is my stored procedure, the data is stored in tables:

```
    Set @EmailFrom =(SELECT EmailFrom FROM tblEmailDesign where EmailID = @EmailID )
    Set @EmailTo =(SELECT EmailTo FROM tblEmailDesign where EmailId = @EmailID )

    Insert into tblEmailsend([EmailID][EmailSubject],[EmailTo],[EmailFrom],[EmailBody],[EmailComment])
select @EmailID @EmailFrom,@EmailTo,[EmailSubject],[EmailBody],@EmailComment from tblEmaildesign
where EmailID=@EmailID

END
```

This is my calling code in C#:

```
protected void submit(object sender, EventArgs e)

        SqlParameter EmailTo = new SqlParameter("@EmailTo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200);
        EmailTo.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        scom.Parameters.Add(EmailTo);

        SqlParameter EmailFrom = new SqlParameter("@EmailFrom", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200);
        EmailFrom.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        string To = EmailTo;

        String FRom = EmailFrom;
        scom.Parameters.Add(EmailFrom);

        mail message = new mail();

        mailsystem.Esendmail(To,From);

        try {
            scom.Connection.Open();
            scom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            scom.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        } finally {
            scom.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the Output parameter values from the stored procedure after you have executed it:

```
protected void submit(object sender, EventArgs e)

    using (SqlCommand scom = new SqlCommand("spx_Send_Status_Mail", new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EPOCHSConnectionString"].ConnectionString))) {

        scom.CommandType =CommandType.StoredProcedure;    
        SqlParameter EmailTo = new SqlParameter("@EmailTo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200);
        EmailTo.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        scom.Parameters.Add(EmailTo);    
        SqlParameter EmailFrom = new SqlParameter("@EmailFrom", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200);
        EmailFrom.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        scom.Parameters.Add(EmailFrom);

        try {
            scom.Connection.Open();
            scom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            scom.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        } finally {
            scom.Connection.Close();
        }

        mail message = new mail();

        //Get output parameters after executing query
        string to = EmailTo.Value.ToString();
        string from = EmailFrom.Value.ToString();
        //Pass To and From email addresses to the ESendmail function
        mailsystem.Esendmail(to,from);
    }
}
```

Comment: i did that still the values are not being passed..more help will be appreciated..

Comment: Can you be more specific, when you step through the code do you retrieve the Output values successfully? If not then run SQL Profiler and check the values are being returned. Its hard to say because the SQL query is incorrect, you're missing a comma after @EmailId: `select @EmailID @EmailFrom,@EmailTo`

Comment: I think while formatting code here i missed comma but in my stored procedure i have done it correctly and i executed each query and i can see values being stored there.I am getting this ERROR:Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'myname@gmail.com'to data type int

Comment: @nitharaj Care to accept so everyone know your problem is solved? cheers: